# Java IMAP fetch mail performance optimiziation in large mailboxes

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap, fetch

I am using java mail API to get all messages in a large mailbox (ex. 5000 mails) using IMAP with all properties of message (body, headers, attachments etc) and store in database. When using FetchProfile with

```
profile.add(IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.MESSAGE);
```

The whole process finishes quickly, but because we used MESSAGE as fetch profile, there is the danger we get out of memory by this block when the size of messages array is large:

```
Message[] messages = folder.getMessagesByUID(1, Long.MAXVALUE);

// line which may cause OutOfMemory
folder.fetch(messages, profile);
```

*Option1:*

Fetch messages by part when calling

```
folder.getMessagesByUID(1, 1000);
folder.fetch(messages, profile);

// Iterate the messages array, process first 1000 messages
// store in the db and call
message.invalidateHeaders();

// Handle next block
folder.getMessagesByUID(1001, 2000);

folder.fetch(messages, profile);
```

*Option2:*

Or do not use `FetchProfileItem.MESSAGE` at all, ony use `ENVELOPE` and `FLAGS`?

Lastly, what is your opionion about: 
Handling content of message body for optimized performance? I think for messages with less 100K size, we may use `getContent()` but for large messages `InputStream` should be applied?

Comment: I don't think there's a single correct answer here.  It may depend on the speed of your mail server vs. the speed of your database server.  Processing the messages in chunks will definitely help prevent running out of memory, but of course it's still not a guarantee.  You might want to use multiple threads where one thread is doing the fetch for the next chunk while the other thread is processing the data from the previous chunk.  You should probably always use getInputStream to read the body of the message.  Or use writeTo if you want to save the entire MIME content of the message.